# AWS CDK: Error when deploying Redis ElastiCache: Subnet group belongs to a different VPC than CacheCluster

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache, aws-cdk

**Summary**

I am trying to deploy a Redis ElastiCache Cluster on AWS using CDK.

I want the cluster to be within a VPC for security reasons.

My code (see supra) defines a VPC, a security group, a cache subnet group (linked to vpc private subnets) and the cache cluster (linked to both cache subnet group and the security group).

With `cdk deploy`, the deployment goes well until I receive this error:

```
ACL_redis (ACLredis) Subnet group [default] belongs to a different VPC [vpc-326ce55b] than [vpc-0c45b593f3a5fdc4d] (Service: AmazonElastiCache; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 901398f4-c355-418d-921b-65e6c52dfe3a)
```

**What I tried**

While disabling the rollback, it appears that the cache cluster is created in the default VPC of the region rather than the VPC defined within my stack.
I do not understand why Cloud Formation is doing that, as both the security group and the cache subnet group are linked to the stack's VPC.

There is no reference to the region default VPC at all.

**Some code**

Here is the CDK code

```
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_stepfunctions,
    aws_lambda,
    aws_stepfunctions_tasks,
    aws_sqs,
    aws_elasticache,
    aws_ec2,
)

PROJECT_CODE = 'ACL'


class AclAwsCdkLearningStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        vpc = aws_ec2.Vpc(self, f"{PROJECT_CODE}_vpc",
                          cidr="10.0.0.0/16"
                          )

        security_group = aws_ec2.SecurityGroup(
            scope=self,
            id=f"{PROJECT_CODE}_security_group",
            vpc=vpc,
        )

        private_subnets_ids = [ps.subnet_id for ps in vpc.private_subnets]

        cache_subnet_group = aws_elasticache.CfnSubnetGroup(
            scope=self,
            id=f"{PROJECT_CODE}_cache_subnet_group",
            subnet_ids=private_subnets_ids,  # todo: add list of subnet ids here
            description="subnet group for redis",
        )

        redis_cluster = aws_elasticache.CfnCacheCluster(
            scope=self,
            id=f"{PROJECT_CODE}_redis",
            engine="redis",
            cache_node_type="cache.t2.small",
            num_cache_nodes=1,
            cache_subnet_group_name=cache_subnet_group.cache_subnet_group_name,
            vpc_security_group_ids=[security_group.security_group_id],
        )

        redis_cluster.add_depends_on(cache_subnet_group)
```

Here is the resulting JSON CloudFormation code:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
        "EnableDnsHostnames": true,
        "EnableDnsSupport": true,
        "InstanceTenancy": "default",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/Resource"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet1SubnetAB5536F8": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/19",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-3a",
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet1"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
            "Value": "Public"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-type",
            "Value": "Public"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet1/Subnet"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet1RouteTable973DCC99": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet1/RouteTable"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation07D70069": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet1RouteTable973DCC99"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet1SubnetAB5536F8"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet1/RouteTableAssociation"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet1DefaultRoute5F1B7BC7": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet1RouteTable973DCC99"
        },
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "GatewayId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcIGWA284CC51"
        }
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "ACLvpcVPCGWA01262F1"
      ],
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet1/DefaultRoute"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet1EIP0233C01E": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
      "Properties": {
        "Domain": "vpc",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet1/EIP"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet1NATGateway7D889FAC": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NatGateway",
      "Properties": {
        "AllocationId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ACLvpcPublicSubnet1EIP0233C01E",
            "AllocationId"
          ]
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet1SubnetAB5536F8"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet1/NATGateway"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet2Subnet1243F1B8": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.32.0/19",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-3b",
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet2"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
            "Value": "Public"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-type",
            "Value": "Public"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet2/Subnet"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet2RouteTableBFA33E2A": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet2/RouteTable"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet2RouteTableAssociation0E367E2F": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet2RouteTableBFA33E2A"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet2Subnet1243F1B8"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet2/RouteTableAssociation"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet2DefaultRoute6918C2C0": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet2RouteTableBFA33E2A"
        },
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "GatewayId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcIGWA284CC51"
        }
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "ACLvpcVPCGWA01262F1"
      ],
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet2/DefaultRoute"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet2EIPBB2E0F7F": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
      "Properties": {
        "Domain": "vpc",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet2/EIP"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet2NATGatewayA823B2BD": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NatGateway",
      "Properties": {
        "AllocationId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ACLvpcPublicSubnet2EIPBB2E0F7F",
            "AllocationId"
          ]
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet2Subnet1243F1B8"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet2/NATGateway"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet3Subnet74DB8A91": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.64.0/19",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-3c",
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet3"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
            "Value": "Public"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-type",
            "Value": "Public"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet3/Subnet"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet3RouteTable48D5C590": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet3"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet3/RouteTable"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet3RouteTableAssociation6304EEEC": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet3RouteTable48D5C590"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet3Subnet74DB8A91"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet3/RouteTableAssociation"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet3DefaultRoute5ED7E66D": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet3RouteTable48D5C590"
        },
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "GatewayId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcIGWA284CC51"
        }
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "ACLvpcVPCGWA01262F1"
      ],
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet3/DefaultRoute"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet3EIP2A75DA44": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
      "Properties": {
        "Domain": "vpc",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet3"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet3/EIP"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPublicSubnet3NATGateway88BC6345": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NatGateway",
      "Properties": {
        "AllocationId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ACLvpcPublicSubnet3EIP2A75DA44",
            "AllocationId"
          ]
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet3Subnet74DB8A91"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet3"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PublicSubnet3/NATGateway"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet1SubnetB88404CC": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.96.0/19",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-3a",
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet1"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
            "Value": "Private"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-type",
            "Value": "Private"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet1/Subnet"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet1RouteTable52EFE8B4": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet1/RouteTable"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet1RouteTableAssociation07BBA734": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet1RouteTable52EFE8B4"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet1SubnetB88404CC"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet1/RouteTableAssociation"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet1DefaultRoute1D5645F3": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet1RouteTable52EFE8B4"
        },
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "NatGatewayId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet1NATGateway7D889FAC"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet1/DefaultRoute"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet2Subnet63321773": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.128.0/19",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-3b",
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet2"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
            "Value": "Private"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-type",
            "Value": "Private"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet2/Subnet"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet2RouteTable66EECACC": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet2/RouteTable"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet2RouteTableAssociationB47D85D6": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet2RouteTable66EECACC"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet2Subnet63321773"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet2/RouteTableAssociation"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet2DefaultRoute692EE131": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet2RouteTable66EECACC"
        },
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "NatGatewayId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet2NATGatewayA823B2BD"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet2/DefaultRoute"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet3SubnetC5349B6D": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.160.0/19",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-3c",
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet3"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
            "Value": "Private"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-type",
            "Value": "Private"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet3/Subnet"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet3RouteTableFCCC4D72": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet3"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet3/RouteTable"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet3RouteTableAssociationD5EEF6F8": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet3RouteTableFCCC4D72"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet3SubnetC5349B6D"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet3/RouteTableAssociation"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet3DefaultRoute6D60CB6B": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet3RouteTableFCCC4D72"
        },
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "NatGatewayId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcPublicSubnet3NATGateway88BC6345"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/PrivateSubnet3/DefaultRoute"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcIGWA284CC51": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
      "Properties": {
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/IGW"
      }
    },
    "ACLvpcVPCGWA01262F1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        },
        "InternetGatewayId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcIGWA284CC51"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_vpc/VPCGW"
      }
    },
    "ACLsecuritygroupF744FA96": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_security_group",
        "SecurityGroupEgress": [
          {
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "Description": "Allow all outbound traffic by default",
            "IpProtocol": "-1"
          }
        ],
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "ACLvpcAC1CD0C2"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_security_group/Resource"
      }
    },
    "ACLcachesubnetgroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::SubnetGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "Description": "subnet group for redis",
        "SubnetIds": [
          {
            "Ref": "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet1SubnetB88404CC"
          },
          {
            "Ref": "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet2Subnet63321773"
          },
          {
            "Ref": "ACLvpcPrivateSubnet3SubnetC5349B6D"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_cache_subnet_group"
      }
    },
    "ACLredis": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster",
      "Properties": {
        "CacheNodeType": "cache.t2.small",
        "Engine": "redis",
        "NumCacheNodes": 1,
        "VpcSecurityGroupIds": [
          {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "ACLsecuritygroupF744FA96",
              "GroupId"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "ACLcachesubnetgroup"
      ],
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "acl-aws-cdk-learning/ACL_redis"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Bash stuff:

```
(.env) acl-aws-cdk-learning % cdk deploy
This deployment will make potentially sensitive changes according to your current security approval level (--require-approval broadening).
Please confirm you intend to make the following modifications:

Security Group Changes
┌───┬───────────────────────────────┬─────┬────────────┬─────────────────┐
│   │ Group                         │ Dir │ Protocol   │ Peer            │
├───┼───────────────────────────────┼─────┼────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ + │ ${ACL_security_group.GroupId} │ Out │ Everything │ Everyone (IPv4) │
└───┴───────────────────────────────┴─────┴────────────┴─────────────────┘
(NOTE: There may be security-related changes not in this list. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1299)

Do you wish to deploy these changes (y/n)? y
acl-aws-cdk-learning: deploying...
acl-aws-cdk-learning: creating CloudFormation changeset...
  0/38 | 11:00:17 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CDK::Metadata                    | CDKMetadata 
  0/38 | 11:00:17 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::EC2::InternetGateway             | ACL_vpc/IGW (ACLvpcIGWA284CC51) 
 (...)
 20/38 | 11:00:53 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::ElastiCache::SubnetGroup         | ACL_cache_subnet_group (ACLcachesubnetgroup) Resource creation Initiated
 21/38 | 11:00:53 | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::ElastiCache::SubnetGroup         | ACL_cache_subnet_group (ACLcachesubnetgroup) 
 21/38 | 11:00:55 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster        | ACL_redis (ACLredis) 
 22/38 | 11:00:56 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster        | ACL_redis (ACLredis) Subnet group [default] belongs to a different VPC [vpc-326ce55b] than [vpc-0c45b593f3a5fdc4d] (Service: AmazonElastiCache; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 901398f4-c355-418d-921b-65e6c52dfe3a)
        obj._wrapSandboxCode (/Users/private/Git/acl-aws-cdk-learning/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7761:49)
        \_ Kernel._wrapSandboxCode (/Users/private/Git/acl-aws-cdk-learning/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:8221:20)
        \_ Kernel._create (/Users/private/Git/acl-aws-cdk-learning/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7761:26)
        \_ Kernel.create (/Users/private/Git/acl-aws-cdk-learning/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7508:21)
        \_ KernelHost.processRequest (/Users/private/Git/acl-aws-cdk-learning/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7296:28)
        \_ KernelHost.run (/Users/private/Git/acl-aws-cdk-learning/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7236:14)
        \_ Immediate.setImmediate [as _onImmediate] (/Users/private/Git/acl-aws-cdk-learning/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7239:37)
        \_ runCallback (timers.js:694:18)
        \_ tryOnImmediate (timers.js:665:5)
        \_ processImmediate (timers.js:647:5)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I can see that CacheSubnetGroupName is missing in the CacheCluster definition in the generated template. That is why the cache is using the default VPC.

CDK omits your subnet group definition as you assign it incorrectly.
When using a Cfn resource, you should refer to other resources in your code using `ref` instead of assigning the resource directly as you did.

Your code should work just by updating the following line of your code.

```
redis_cluster = aws_elasticache.CfnCacheCluster(
     ...
     cache_subnet_group_name=cache_subnet_group.ref
)
```